# How can I send the installed files from USB drive to hard drive?

Tags: usb, 20.04, mount

I am a newcomer to Ubuntu. I was not really sure if I should install Ibuntu on my HDD, but now I am sure it is not a bad go, but I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS in my USB (128GB SanDisk), and I want your help to safely send my files to `/dev/sda3`.
I thought I could copy & paste the files when I use Windows 10.

The USB would not open the file (pop-up saying I should format the drive), also sometimes when I mount my disk it reads the folders as read only (but next time I startup it won't). Can anyone help me out and, try to explain the steps?

Comment: Windows will not read Linux formatted partitions. And the few tools that try in read only mode, are not considered reliable. But you can easily read & write NTFS partitions from Linux. But you must have Windows fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Just copy personal files? If so it is far easier to boot from the USB, mount windows and copy files over to windows.  We have 99% support for NTFS, Microsoft has no native support for EXT.